# curl returns (7) ["Failed to connect"] but although configured with --retry 100, it does not retry

Tags: command-line, networking, server, curl

I try to download a file from server using curl command. The command usually ends successfully but I wanted to check if it can handle errors the way I intended, so I added:

```
--retry 10 --retry-delay 10
```

and pulled the `ETH` cable out. When I re-executed the command, it returned after less than 3 seconds with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.10.10.10 port 21: No route to host`. As I understand, this error is a transient error, and so, by quoting:

> --retry
>
> > If a **transient error** is returned when curl tries to perform a transfer, **it will retry** this number of times before giving up. Setting the number to 0 makes curl do no retries (which is the default). **Transient error means either: a timeout, an FTP 4xx response code** or an HTTP 408 or 5xx response code.

I expected it do just fine.

Why didn't it go over the required 100 seconds (10 times 10 seconds)?

**Versions:**

```
curl -V
curl 7.60.0 (powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.60.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.8.0

uname -a
Linux SmartSwitch 3.4.52 #1 PREEMPT Tue Aug 21 16:41:14 IDT 2018 ppc unknown

cat /etc/*-release file.
Release date = Tue Aug 21 13:36:48 2018 UTC
Release user = ubuntu
Release host = ubuntu-desktop
Release dir  = /home/ubuntu/ltib-1031
SCM wtag     = none
SCM tag      = none
Release tag  = none
App version  = 9.1.1

lsb_release -a
-sh: lsb_release: command not found
```

Comment: @ClsForCookies -  What Ubuntu version are you using ?

Comment: Not sure. I tried all the commands from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88644/how-to-check-os-and-version-using-a-linux-command but all I got was the `uname -a` I already added in the post

Comment: So what did `lsb_release -a` say ?

Comment: its a in-house version of ubuntu. Could this somehow affect the curl retry feature? I thought only the curl version is relevant here

Comment: That depends on how it was build. But since "an in-house version" isn't an official Ubuntu variant, it might be off topic on this site.

Comment: I tried it again on an official Ubuntu 14.04. This time I didn't have certificates required, but nevertheless, there were no retries...

Comment: `No Route to Host` is not in the list of transient errors. But `could not resolve host` is also not in the list and retries work for me.